# OWL limit individual to have only one type of ObjectProperty

Tags: owl, protege

I have this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGHD1.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7apGR.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCSNU.png

And i want to force to every individual of class Machine to have only isInState relation

Comment: `Machine SubClassOf isInState max 1` would be the axiom. But this wouldn't be a constraint as you might think, but just an axiom for inference. OWL has no concept of "constraints" like in for example databases. All the axiom does is to make multiple `isInState` values being `owl:sameAs` - unless you make all individuals `owl:differentFrom` each other, which then would lead to an inconsistent ontology

Comment: Yes i want to reflect inconsistency if Machine has more than 1 MachineState

Comment: as I said, i) then add the subclass axiom and also ii) an axiom that makes all contained individuals distinct. Otherwise it won't work because there is no Unique Names Assumption in OWL. For proper constraint, people use different stuff like SHACL etc.